# mvc CompareAttribute not showing up even if referenced System.Web.Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I have a problem using Compare on my model. I want compare two fields, password and confirmpassword respectively and after some thorough search I found out that I can use the "CompareAttribute" so I thought it'll be on the dataannotation namespace but it isn't. Realizing that I was looking at the wrong one I search as to where and soon found out that it's on System.Web.Mvc. But the problem is, it wasn't finding it (red squiggly lines showing)..

Ok so I looked at my references and viewed the System.Web.Mvc dll and it has two instances, 1 with a **[2.0.0.0]** and another with a **[3.0.0.0]**. the **version 3** has the CompareAttribute but I can't seem to access it.. **Am I supposed to manually direct the project to look at the version 3? If so, how?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have any reference to the System.Web.Mvc V2 assembly in an ASP.NET MVC 3 application. You should only use System.Web.Mvc V3 which contains the [Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.compareattribute.aspx) attribute. If you are still using an old version of ASP.NET MVC you may take a look at the [upgrate notes](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#upgrading). You should also be targeting .NET 4.0.